# Sencha build failed

Tags: java, extjs

I use Sencha Ext-JS 4.2.2 and Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203

Ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

Yesterday, it runs well, today not.

I have tried to create a new empty project with `sencha -sdk <ext4 path> generate app "MyApp" <path>` and then `sencha build` without any other message than the following stack:

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.0.203
[ERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
     at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.FileUtil.readFile(FileUtil.java:170)
     at com.sencha.tools.compiler.jsb.projects.JsbBuilder.processBuild(JsbBuilder.java:29)
     at com.sencha.command.build.JsbCommand.execute(JsbCommand.java:15)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:149)
```

What's happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct command is

sencha **app** build

I don't known what's the command `sencha build` does...

Comment: That's it!  I would have spent hours trying to debug this.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm embarrassed about how helpful this was to me just now.

Comment: Just spent 2 hrs trying to figure this out - thank you!  Very hard to find any info about this.  The key way searching on just one of the error lines.